# keras model prediction is nan after saving and loading

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I trained a neural network with google colab.
I saved the neural network using `joblib.dump()`

I then loaded the model on my PC using `joblib.load()`

I made a prediction on the exact same sample, using the same model, on both colab and my PC.  On colab, it has an output of `[[0.51]]`.  On my pc, it has an output of `[[nan]]`.

The model summary reports that the architecture of the model is the same.
I checked the weights of the model I loaded on my PC, and the model on colab, and the weights are the exact same.

Any ideas as to what I can do?  Thank you.

Quick update:  even if I change all of my inputs to zero, the prediction is *still* nan.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know keras has its own function to save the model such as `model.save('file.h5')`, and the `joblib` library is used to save sklearn models.

Comment: I tried this, I still have the same issue.
After some investigation, I think it's because the GPU is for some reason leading to some nan weights, which for some reason is not a problem for GPU but is a problem for CPU?